# R markdown won't knit despite accurate code chunks. Error= missing ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2, install.packages

I am trying to knit to pdf in R markdown. My code chunks are correct and producing the correct plots, but it keeps giving me the error when I try to knit.

The error message is:

> ```
> Error in ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy)):
>   could not find function "ggplot"
> Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval
> Execution halted
> ```

I've re-installed tidyverse and ggplot2 several times. I've also ran the library() function for both.

I'm getting this message when I call the library function for ggplot2.

> ```
> > library(ggplot2)
> Learn more about the underlying theory at https://ggplot2-book.org/
> ```

`install.packages`, `library`, and `update.packages` did not solve the problem. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including `library(tidyverse)` or `library(ggplot2)` in the RMarkdown file. When you knit an RMarkdown file, it will not use materials in your environment - it only uses the code you provide in the file.

Comment: how do I include that in the RMarkdown file?

Comment: You can add the `library(tidyverse)` statement in one of your code chunks in your RMarkdown file; don't just run it in the console. I usually add it to my first code chunk. Let me know if this fixes your problem

Answer (score 0):

@mfg3z0 , you are correct! Thank you!

I needed to add the ggplot to Rmarkdown.

I ran library(ggplot2) in a chunk in the RMarkdown file.

I was able to knit my file after that.